# Why would `import dataTables from 'datatables.net'` work on some machines but not others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, datatables

We have a single-file Vue 1.x component that is a wrapper of dataTables. The basics of it look like this:

```
<template>
...
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import $ from 'jquery';
import dataTables from 'datatables.net';
import dataTablesSelect from 'datatables.net-select';
import dataTablesColReorder from 'datatables.net-colreorder';
import dataTablesScroller from 'datatables.net-scroller';

const Table = Vue.extend({
    ...
    created() {
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';
        ...
        this.dataTable = this.$table.DataTable(this.options);
    },
});
</script>
```

The component is compiled via our Webpack configuration.

This has worked just fine. Recently we have been porting the codebase to Vue 2.x. On mine as well as my coworker's machines, the ported component works great. However once it has been built on our build server, using the same command, it instead throws this error on page load:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'ext' of undefined`
referencing the line above:
`$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';`

It seems then that when built on our build server, dataTables is not actually getting properly imported. I can confirm it is the actual generated app.js causing the issue, as downloading it and running it locally generates the same error. I've tried everything I can think of to match environments including making sure node/npm versions are the same and `rm -rf`ing node_modules. Yet we still repeatedly get the same results.

I'm out of ideas on where else to debug, as admittedly I am not well versed in the mechanics of a webpack build. What could possibly be causing this to seemingly only work on certain machines?

Answer (score 1):

That error means there is no $.fn.dataTable object.

Post your webpack mix file and how you're using jQuery.  I'm suspecting that external/multiple jQuery conflict here, where you import one jQuery and the DataTable is initialized on a different jQuery.  See if this work.

```js
// Right below your imports, initialize everything you imported
// this make sure fn.dataTable get initialized on the imported jQuery
// which is reference as $ in this case
dataTables(window, $);
dataTablesSelect(window, $);
dataTablesColReorder(window, $);
dataTablesScroller(window, $);
```

Shameless plug, check out my wrapper here - https://github.com/niiknow/vue-datatables-net - it may help make things easier for you.  Even with my wrapper, you have to still know which jQuery you're initializing it on.